# Show one item from that filtered row with query string on a label control with C# and data set class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm designing a web store with Asp.net. To transfer from the list of products page to individual products page,  have used query string URL and have used access data source control as interface of microsoft  access file. In individual products page have used access data source  that used query string parameter from previous page (list of products page) to filter a special product row. I would like to know how can I with C# and dataset class show one item from that filtered row on a label control?

Below is `AccessDataSource` in  product page HTML code:

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/test.mdb" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [test] WHERE ([productname] = ?)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="productname" QueryStringField="productname" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:AccessDataSource>
```

Comment: Can you maybe clarify your question? It's quite confusing. Do you want to display a row of data you already filtered out on a label control?

Comment: @mota Specify your need Not your code.

Comment: no.i want show an item of that row on a label

Comment: Take a Look [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-get-Selected-Row-cell-value-from-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx),it could be same that you want

Comment: it is not the same. in my case i have access source and query string filter and must use dataset clase. but i dont know how?